Infinite Loops, Ctrl + C, and Python IDLE Shell
I'm very new to programming and am learning Python through Automate the Boring Stuff. I'm looking at While Loops and put the following into the file editor window:
name = ''
while name != 'your name':
     print('Please type your name.')
     name = input()
print('Thank you!')

In the interactive shell of IDLE, the author uses the following as an example of While Loops:
>>>
Please type your name.
your name
Thank you!
>>> while True:
          print('Hello!')

And then Hello! appears dozens of times. The book says to click Shell -> Restart Shell, or to use Ctrl + C to interrupt the execution. This does not work for me.
I'm using Python IDLE Shell 3.12.2, Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5 16IRL8, and Windows 11.
I can't interrupt the execution as this bug is happening. I can only do this when the program is not going haywire. Otherwise, Ctrl + C, Ctrl + Fn + F6, and navigating the toolbar all work.
While the loop is happening, my keystrokes are ignored, and the toolbar is frozen when I try to click on anything. Eventually, I am told that Python is not responding, and I close the program. I don't want to lose my work in the future, so I would like to know how to fix this.
I have tried Ctrl + Fn + F6 to Restart Shell, which again only works when I'm not running the program above. I have tried a few other keys like D and \ instead of C as well, and these do not work. I do not see a Break or Pause key on my keyboard.

what is your question exactly?

while True: runs forever since the condition will never be false. its no bug whatsoever

This is a known bug, no resolution currently.

@Mr.Irrelevant Yes, I'm aware that the program is supposed to run forever. I do not have any questions about the code. This was part of a tutorial explaining what to do if your program is running forever and you want it to stop without closing the window. The book suggested Ctrl + C, which is not working for me. I meant to ask if there is another key sequence that could work, or some other solution, but it appears this is a problem with the IDLE software itself according to the other commenter here.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you! After reading your comment, I tried this in Mu and was easily able to interrupt the execution like in the example. Thanks for helping me learn!

There are situations in which ^C fails to stop a loop executing in CPython in a  standard terminal window.  In at least some of these, ^F6 in IDLE works to stop the loop without closing and losing previous work .  There are others situations, such as the print loops here, where IDLE is much worse.  An overt while True: print(...) is at least visible and avoidable.

I don't believe that you would lose your work, but needless to say, don't use while loops that print something unless you have a very good reason for it. And most of the programs you'll write in the future will not have this problem. @Abdul Aziz Barkat has a good answer for why this occurs.
